# Comparing Numeric Value in Batch File with LEQ Keep Returning False Value

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hi I'm new in Batch File and still learning.
I would like to ask about Symbol Equivalent in Batch File.
I have a batch file to compare year.

```
IF %YEAR% LEQ 2017 (
    echo true
) else (
    echo false
)
```

However, it keeps returning false value, even when the values are match or values are mismatch.
Am I wrong put the symbol in Batch File?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What is the content of `%year%`, does it contains other characters that are not numeric? Are they greater then `2^31-1`? If you can, please show how the `%year%` is set.

Comment: Also, are you having the `if` statement inside another `if` or `for` loop? That would make a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

The '%year%' variable seem like you want to get the year number, also you just new to batch file. So I want to show you the '%date%' variable.
If you only type `echo %date%` , you'll see the text like: `MM/DD/YYYY`

The problem is, you only need the year number. Now you have to use like this:

```
set year=%date:~6,4%
IF year% LEQ 2017 (
  echo true
) else (
  echo false
)
```

**set year=%date:~6,4%** mean you only get the number from char #6 (front of year number '2') and from char #6, you only get 4 more char (from #6 to end of string)

Hope this helpful, and remember, there is no %year% variable.